# How to sign ECDSA with pem private key?

Tags: digital-signature, ruby, ecdsa

I have private key with pem format.

```
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHQCAQEEIBAFWFAlCWPb8IvM4yHLLKBIN/mEJU9cZnM5JD2U2EmAoAcGBSuBBAAK
oUQDQgAErMGUjbHcEf7Gk9gVOOlWdqSaGc0YhE5HBPqhoniBUG8MTx5AT7mxtuyn
QkydMeOciHyvvyU0gf81UW9udef2nA==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
```

I want to sign with ruby code like following.

```
require 'ecdsa'
def sign(str)
    digest = Digest::SHA256.digest(str) 
    temp_key = str.size 
    signature = ECDSA.sign($group, $private_key, digest, temp_key)
end
```

I want to know how to code for reading PEM private key file and using to sign.

Answer (score 2):

To parse your key stored in PEM format, you can use the openssl module: `sudo gem install openssl`

Using this module, you will extract the private key this way: `OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new(pemcontent).private_key`

Note that your private key is based on the **secp256k1** elliptic curve:

```
% openssl ec -text 2>&1 << EOF | grep OID
-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHQCAQEEIBAFWFAlCWPb8IvM4yHLLKBIN/mEJU9cZnM5JD2U2EmAoAcGBSuBBAAK
oUQDQgAErMGUjbHcEf7Gk9gVOOlWdqSaGc0YhE5HBPqhoniBUG8MTx5AT7mxtuyn
QkydMeOciHyvvyU0gf81UW9udef2nA==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----
EOF
ASN1 OID: secp256k1
```

Therefore, the first parameter to give to `EDSA.sign()` must be `ECDSA::Group::Secp256k1`. This is an object that contains the parameters that define this curve.

Finally, here is your code, on which I've made the changes needed to make it work:

```
require 'ecdsa'
require 'openssl'

def sign(str)
  pemcontent = "-----BEGIN EC PRIVATE KEY-----
MHQCAQEEIBAFWFAlCWPb8IvM4yHLLKBIN/mEJU9cZnM5JD2U2EmAoAcGBSuBBAAK
oUQDQgAErMGUjbHcEf7Gk9gVOOlWdqSaGc0YhE5HBPqhoniBUG8MTx5AT7mxtuyn
QkydMeOciHyvvyU0gf81UW9udef2nA==
-----END EC PRIVATE KEY-----"
  digest = Digest::SHA256.digest(str)
  temp_key = str.size
  signature = ECDSA.sign(ECDSA::Group::Secp256k1, OpenSSL::PKey::EC.new(pemcontent).private_key, digest, temp_key)
  return signature
end
```

Note: the value of temp_key should be generated with a more random way than using the length of the message to sign, like you did in your example code (it is a **very** **very** bad idea since soon or later, you will sign two messages with the same length, and this could let your private key been discovered).